# GetDateFileModified for Daylight Savings Time

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

```
function DateTimeToFileTime(FileTime: TDateTime): TFileTime;
var
  LocalFileTime, Ft: TFileTime;
  SystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  Result.dwLowDateTime := 0;
  Result.dwHighDateTime := 0;
  DateTimeToSystemTime(FileTime, SystemTime);
  SystemTimeToFileTime(SystemTime, LocalFileTime);
  LocalFileTimeToFileTime(LocalFileTime, Ft);
  Result := Ft;
end;

function ExtractShortDate(ATimeIn: TDateTime): string;
// Convert DateTime to short date string
begin
  Result := FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy', ATimeIn);
end;

function ExtractTime(ATimeIn: TDateTime): string;
// Convert DateTime to am/pm time string
begin
  Result := FormatDateTime('hh:mm AM/PM', ATimeIn);
end;

function GetDateFileModified(AFileName: string): string;
// Return the file modified date as a string in local time
var
  SR: TSearchRec;
  UTCTime: Windows.TFileTime;
  GMTST: Windows.TSystemTime;
  LocalST: Windows.TSystemTime;
  ModifyDT: TDateTime;
  TZ: Windows._TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION;
begin
  Result := '';
  if FindFirst(AFileName, faAnyFile, SR) = 0 then
  begin
    UTCTime := SR.FindData.ftLastWriteTime;
    if FileTimeToSystemTime(UTCTime, GMTST) then
    begin
       // Get Timezone Information
      if GetTimeZoneInformation(TZ) <> 0 then
        if SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(@TZ, GMTST, LocalST) then
        begin
          ModifyDT := SystemTimeToDateTime(LocalST);
          Result := ExtractShortDate(ModifyDT) + ' ' + ExtractTime(ModifyDT);
        end
        else
        begin
          TaskMessageDlg('Unable To Convert Time', 'Unable to convert SystemTime To LocalTime',
            mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
          Result := '';
          exit;
        end;
    end
    else
    begin
      TaskMessageDlg('Unable To Convert Time', 'Unable to convert FileTime To SystemTime',
        mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
      Result := '';
      exit;
    end;
  end
  else
    TaskMessageDlg('File Not Found', ExtractFileName(AFileName) + ' does not exist.',
      mtInformation, [mbOk], 0);
  FindClose(SR);
end;
```

The original code posted did not return the correct time.  The original code was replaced with working code so that others may find this beneficial.

**Update**: The code provides the correct time now thanks to all that assisted.

Comment: Is your file on an NTFS file system (where all file timestamps are in UTC) or on a FAT file system (where they are usually not)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is highlighted in the MSDN docs for FileTimeToLocalFileTime:

> FileTimeToLocalFileTime uses the current settings for the time zone and daylight saving time. Therefore, if it is daylight saving time, this function will take daylight saving time into account, even if the time you are converting is in standard time. You can use the following sequence of functions as an alternative.
>
> FileTimeToSystemTime / SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime / SystemTimeToFileTime

You need to use the three functions specified whenever you look at a file after a daylight savings change that was created before the change (but this method of course also works when you and the file creation are both on the same side of the daylight savings change).

Comment: How do you know when you "look at a file after a daylight savings change was created before the change"?  If you start with a TDateTIme what order are the functions called?

Comment: @Bill: you pass the original UTC `FILETIME` from `FindFirst()` to `FileTimeToSystemTime()`, then pass that to `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()` to get a Local `SYSTEMTIME`. `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime()` will do all the work for you. It compares the input `SYSTEMTIME` to the specified timezone's standard and daylight timestamps when doing the conversion.

Comment: @Bill: If the file was created on the local machine (or at least on a machine in the same timezone as the local machine) and in the current year, you can pass `NULL` to the `lpTimeZone` parameter of `SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTim()`, otherwise you have to provide a `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` struct for the desired timezone of the desired year. You might be abl to get that information from the Registry, [as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725481.aspx), or you can use an online timezone website to look it up.

Comment: @Bill you don't need to know in advance that Daylight savings is involved, just use the sequence explained in more detail by Remy in all cases.  I have clarified my answer.

Comment: I have some new code which is providing the incorrect time.  Should I post the code as a new question or modify this one?

Comment: UTC_FILE_Time := SR.FindData.ftLastWriteTime;
    if FileTimeToSystemTime(UTC_FILE_Time, UTC_System_Time) then
      SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(nil, UTC_System_Time, LocalST)

Comment: @frogb - UTCTime: Windows.TFileTime; but SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(nil, UTCTime - must be Windows.TSystemTime, so your suggestion will not even compile.

Comment: UTC_FILE_Time should be declared as a Filetime.  UTC_SYSTEM_Time should be declared as a SystemTime.  Apologies for assuming this was obvious.  Forget your UTCTime, its name simply confuses.  And please go to MSDN and check the definitions of these functions if you still cannot get it to compile.

Comment: Thanks to all... it provides the correct time now... Text updated with successful code.  Remy, frogb thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad you quoted that paragraph from MSDN, as the function no longer gives that warning.