# Convert File Time To Julian Date in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have a problem getting file modified time as julian date. My **Delphi 2010** looks like this:

```
AHandle := FindFirstFile(PChar('C:\*'), FindData);
if (AHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) then
begin
     repeat
           if (FindData.dwFileAttributes And FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY = 0) then
                ModifJulianDate := FileTimeToJulianDate(FindData.ftLastWriteTime);

     until Not FindNextFile(AHandle, FindData);
end;
```

The problem is: `FileTimeToJulianDate()` returned result has **one hour offset**, ie. if the file's modified time is 10:01, this code returns 9:01!!

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: You probably want to take daylight saving into account, see [GetDateFileModified for Daylight Savings Time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13178785/576719). The function FileTimeToJulianDate() does not seem to be a Delphi rtl function, you should probably add that code in your question.

Comment: Without `FileTimeToJulianDate` we don't know what you are doing. You also need to specify what the requirement is. Time is all about precise details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functionality that you are looking for, assuming your answer is accurate, is most easily implemented using FileTimeToLocalFileTime.

```
function UTCFileTimeToLocalDateTime(const UTCFileTime: TFileTime): TDateTime;
var
  LocalFileTime: TFileTime;
  LocalSystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  if not FileTimeToLocalFileTime(UTCFileTime, LocalFileTime) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if not FileTimeToSystemTime(LocalFileTime, LocalSystemTime) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(LocalSystemTime);
end;
```

Or if you prefer to use SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime then do so like this:

```
function UTCFileTimeToLocalDateTime(const UTCFileTime: TFileTime): TDateTime;
var
  UTCSystemTime, LocalSystemTime: TSystemTime;
begin
  if not FileTimeToSystemTime(UTCFileTime, UTCSystemTime) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  if not SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(nil, UTCSystemTime, LocalSystemTime) then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(LocalSystemTime);
end;
```

Comment: Your answer is actually better than the one I posted, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With the help of LU RD & the [code posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13178785/576719), I managed to get what I wanted, in case someone need something like this, here's my code:

```
function GetDateFileModified(UTCTime : TFileTime{FindData : TWin32FindData}) : TDateTime;
// Return the file modified date as a string in local time
var
   GMTsystemTime : Windows.TSystemTime;
   LocalSysTime  : Windows.TSystemTime;
   TimeZone      : Windows._TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION;
begin
     Result  := 0;

     // Get Timezone Information
     GetTimeZoneInformation(TimeZone);

     // UTCTime := FindData.ftLastWriteTime;
     if FileTimeToSystemTime(UTCTime, GMTsystemTime) then
     begin
          SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(@TimeZone, GMTsystemTime, LocalSysTime);
          Result := SystemTimeToDateTime(LocalSysTime);
     end;
end;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `GMTsystemTime` should be named `UTCSystemTime`.

Comment: And if you are going to call SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime for active time zone, pass nil as first param